# OpenCart 1.5.0 and Shopping Carts

Tags: shopping-cart, opencart

Been messing about with this new version of openCart and noticed add to cart buttons not working anyone else noticed this, does anyone have a resolution, tried contacting opencart no news yet.

What shopping Carts do you use, whats the best in your opinion. Ive just started doing e-commerce sites and yeah opencart is good but would be good to know others that are as easy to edit themes etc...

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Opencart 1.5 has only recently been release and there has been a lot of bugs fixed since the first release. You mention the add to cart problem do you have a link to view? Do you have the same problem with the default download version?

From my experience Opencart is the best apart from all the built in options its one of the easiest cart to modify to the clients needs. This is a nice [list](http://webtecker.com/2008/04/22/8-best-open-source-shopping-cart-solutions/) of the most popular choices, although I'd say stick with Opencart.